# c# filter datagridview datetime field using sql LIKE

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datetime, datagridview

I have problem when i try to filter data from `datagridview`. I try to filter `datetime` field using `LIKE` and `%` wilcard. When i assign value in `textBoxEdit` like this `12-01` or just put `1` am geting:

[image]

Does i not format and escape good this query string or is inposible to assign integer value to wilcard? Or maybe any other reson for this sintax error.

Another queries work fine just here i have problem:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, created, 120) LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
```

**Check my full code:**

```
 private void searchTextBoxNaziv_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            String selectedColumn = filterSearchCombo.Text;
            String sql = "";

            if(selectedColumn == "ID" && searchTextBoxNaziv.Text is string)
            {
                sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE id LIKE '%" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
            }
            else if(selectedColumn == "Name")
            {
                sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE nameLIKE '%" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
            }
            else if (selectedColumn == "Descr")
            {
                sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE desc LIKE '%" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
            }
            else if (selectedColumn == "Created")
            {
                sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, created, 120) LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";

            }

            else
            {
                sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala";
            }

            GetData(sql);
}
```

**Update:**

```
private void GetData(string sql)
        {
            using (conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

                    dt = new DataTable();
                    bs = new BindingSource();

                    adapter.Fill(dt);

                    bs = new BindingSource();
                    bs.DataSource = dt;

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
                    bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I hope your SELECT statement is for demonstration purposes and you would NEVER write it like that in real-life? That is ripe for injection!

Comment: Am createing litle app only for me and i dont care about injection

Comment: @Ivan it's good that you are creating app for yourself but that being said i think it s wise to follow right coding practices

Comment: Yeah - and use of parameters (as in my example) will prevent the need for expressed conversion - MySQL will parse for you as long as data is of parse-able format.

Comment: It's also a good idea to convert case when doing text searches based on typed input - just in case you forget a capital letter here or there

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to convert date to varchar

```
SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, created, 120) LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'
```

instead use below query

```
SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  created LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'
```

It will simply search data according to where condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem that you stated but there needs to be a space between `name` and `LIKE` in 
`"SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE nameLIKE '%" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'"`, because that query won't work.

As for your problem, since you are saying you are using mysql - you have a syntax error in your `CONVERT` it should be `CONVERT(created, VARCHAR(120))`

Comment: Like i say i have only problem with `else if (selectedColumn == "Created")`  other block work perfect

Comment: Yes, I got that, your problem is the syntax error in the Convert, that is not the convert syntax for mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), created, 120) LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
```

Instead of

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, created, 120) LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
```

refer this link.

convert convert-datetime-to-varchar

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx

OR

TRY this,

```
 sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala WHERE  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, created, 120), 10)
LIKE '" + searchTextBoxNaziv.Text + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void searchTextBoxNaziv_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String selectedColumn = filterSearchCombo.Text;
        String sql = "";

        if (searchTextBoxNaziv.Text.length > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", searchTextBoxNaziv.Text.ToLower());
            switch (selectedColumn)
            {
                case "ID":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", "ID");
                    break;
                case "Name":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", "Name");
                    break;
                case "Descr":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", "Desc");
                    break;
                case "Created":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", whateverCreatedIs);
                    break;
            }
            com.CommandText = "select * from grupe_artikala where lcase(@searchItem) like %@search%";
            //execute SELECT
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I'm really sorry, but I don't have MySQL installed and have to work off memory (no Intellisense). I think this will get you there or close to it. Hope it helps!

```
private void searchTextBoxNaziv_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String selectedColumn = filterSearchCombo.Text;
        String sql = "";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
        com = new MySqlCommand("select * from grupe_artikala where lcase(@searchItem) like %@search%", conn);
        if (searchTextBoxNaziv.Text.length > 0)
        {

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", searchTextBoxNaziv.Text.ToLower());
            switch (selectedColumn)
            {
                case "ID":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", "ID");
                    break;
                case "Name":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", "Name");
                    break;
                case "Descr":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", "Desc");
                    break;
                case "Created":
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchItem", whateverCreatedIs);
                    break;
            }
            GetData(conn, com);
        }
    }
    private void GetData(MySqlConnection conn, MySqlCommand com)
    {

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = com;

            dt = new DataTable();
            bs = new BindingSource();

            da.Fill(dt);

            bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dt;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you use parameters, you don't need to expressly convert as long as the data matches a parse-able format.

Comment: Sorry - missed "my" in sql - I'm sure you know the difference.

Comment: this looks realy good but in my method `GetData(string sql)` am using adapter and am not shure how to optimise your code with my method. See my full method! Check update

Comment: Yes - please share getdata()